# How to remove HTML5 Slider video controller

Tags: android, ios, html, html5-video

I got some problem to implement HTML5 video both on iPhone and Android.
I would like to remove the HTML5 video controller slider while the videos is playing.
The purpose is to make user watch the video from start until end without jumping or stop the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking may not be possible . But try this

1. Set control=false for video tag
2. Implement your own controls http://www.broken-links.com/2009/10/06/building-html5-video-controls-with-javascript/

Bot since your target is iphone/andriod i doubt if it's possible

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've tried all your options before.
no 1. options will make the video freeze and can't play (tried with iphone and htc phone)
no 2. hmm... as your doubt the video will be grow fullscreen and displayed the default media controller

now, actually I'm looking for html5 canvas solution, 
do you know how to draw video on the canvas ?

Comment: sorry no idea buddy, again since ur target is iphone/andriod i doubt if it's possible

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I tried every time to draw with Canvas using every pixel that displayed at video element. In the end, the video have to be displayed (showed) if you try with smartphone. Well, I got good news too, if I declare control=false in video element, then the slider still out, but the slider can't be controlled .. :) thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this tutorial](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/custom-html5-video-player-with-css3-and-jquery/) to build your own player, so you can get rid of anything you don't want.

Comment: hi, thanks. I had tried this, but if you tried to play the video using Android or iPhone devices, it will be play on the device default media player and also grow to fullscreen  .. Actually now I'm looking for draw the video to canvas, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<body >
   <video id="video" src="BO_VS_ST_MT1.webm" width="480px" height="270px"  autoplay    controls >
</video>
<canvas width="400" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black;" ></canvas> 
<script language="Javascript"> 
    window.onload = function(){ initCanvas(); }
    var context;
    function initCanvas(){
        var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
        var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        video.addEventListener("timeupdate", paintFrame, false);
    }
    function paintFrame(){
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 400, 300);
    }
</script>
```

But Ithink It is gonna look so slow :/

Comment: Did you have tested this in mobile device ?

Comment: yeap i did in my iphone 4s but is slow.... and u have to adapt it to the device screen...

Comment: really ? because I did the same way, but I got white screen on device. Actually I hide the original video than tried to copy that to the canvas

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can do this on the iphone - they have strict settings . IT seems to be that the first time a video loads, you are unable to actually play the video without the user interacting with the video frame, which means that it's impossible to click this element if it's not visible. I think it's a waste of processing power to do that anyway.